# Python Extend List Comprehension

Tags: python, python-2.6, python-2.x

I'm trying to make a list comprehension while parsing multiple arguments, which can be single, comma seperated or null values.

The following is a short working piece of code:

```
csv_ip = '192.168.1.1,192.168.1.20'
single_ip = '33.44.33.22'
empty_ip = None

ip_list = [ip for ip in [csv_ip.split(','), single_ip, empty_ip] if ip]
print ip_list
>> [['192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.20'], '33.44.33.22']
```

I'm wondering if I can extend the list when I split the CSV values, so that the list will be as following:

```
['192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.20', '33.44.33.22']
```

Is it possible to extend a list comprehension with another list ?

Comment: If you're using Python 3: `[ip for ip in [*csv_ip.split(','), single_ip, empty_ip] if ip]`.

Comment: I'm using Python 2.6 - I guess it's important that I mention that for future posts.. cheers!

Comment: Yeah, but remember that **always** use `python` tag if your question is about Python. Check the [*Tagging recommendation*](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python-2.x/info) of the [tag:python-2.x] tag info for more details.

Comment: If you want to ask a new question with a code sample that actually applies to your program (i.e., an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), feel free to ask it and I'll move my answer on this question to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just create a single flat list before filtering by "adding" sub-lists:

```
csv_ip = '192.168.1.1,192.168.1.20'
single_ip = '33.44.33.22'
empty_ip = None

ip_list = [ip for ip in csv_ip.split(',') + [single_ip] + [empty_ip] if ip]
print ip_list
>>> ['192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.20', '33.44.33.22']
```

If you want a version that treats all of the argument cases identically, you can use:

```
ip_list = [ip for s in [csv_ip, single_ip, empty_ip] for ip in (s.split(",") if s else [])]
```

Comment: Well, `[ip for ip in csv_ip.split(',') + [single_ip, empty_ip] if ip]` also works fine.

Comment: This worked well for me - if you can edit your answer to include Kevins comment that would be great (since I've marked this as the answer) I'll be using this solution. Cheers

Comment: Doesn't this require that you know which arguments are a single IP or `None`?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Yes, just as in the original example.  I don't know what the actual context of this problem is.  It could of course treat them all as comma-separated IP lists, but if the string can be `None` then something is still required for that.  The point of this solution was to illustrate a mechanism that can be used.  The OP should be able to adapt it as needed.

Comment: The OP is "parsing multiple arguments, which can be single, comma seperated or null values." This solution relies on knowing the category of each argument, and then hard-codes the values.

Comment: I added an alternate version that treats all of the argument cases identically.  The output is identical.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to do an actual `extend`, but you can achieve the same result by using `itertools.chain`

```
from itertools import chain

ip_list = [ip for ip in chain(csv_ip.split(','), [single_ip, empty_ip]) if ip]
```

`itertools.chain` takes in a bunch of iterables, and then iterates over all the elements of the first, then the second, and so on, so you need to send in `single_ip` and `empty_ip` in a list as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since the whole point is that you don't know which arguments will contain comma-separated IPs, which will contain a single IP, and which will contain `None`, you won't get far if you try to hard-code their behavior. Instead, check each argument and process it appropriately:

```
csv_ip = '192.168.1.1,192.168.1.20'
single_ip = '33.44.33.22'
empty_ip = None
args = csv_ip, single_ip, empty_ip
result = [item for arg in args for item in (arg.split(',') if arg else '')]
```

Result:

```
>>> for item in result:
...     print(item)
...
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.20
33.44.33.22
```